# Unexpected token only on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I make an ajax call and on mobile everything works fine but on mobile I saw on logs this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`.

Here is :

```
  var cars = [];

    $('li.cars').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var keyword = { key: $this.data('key'), val: $this.html() };
    cars.push(keyword);
    });


data.append('cars', JSON.stringify(cars));
```

How can I solve this problem?

**EDIT**

I saw something.. I have an input type file, and this thing it happens when i'm loading something in input. If input is empty works fine, if I try to upload..i've got error

```
data.append('myphoto', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);

 <form id="imageUploadForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <label for="" class="input-product">
           <img class="img-upload img-responsive product-image" src="img.png" /><input id="input-1" class="input-upload" type="file" name="myphoto" accept="image/*">
     </label>
 </form>
```

Comment: Here @Pablo [{"key":"size","val":"black11"},{"key":"color","val":"bvcawreq"}]

Comment: I think your error is not caused in this piece of code: it seems to be created by a call to JSON.parse, not JSON.stringify

Comment: if i'm doing json.parse i've got [object Object]...and won't work

Comment: a call to JSON parse is causing the problem, if you are not calling it directly, it may be being called by jQuery

Comment: There is something else going on, I just ran your code on chrome on a mobile phone and it works fine

Comment: @Ken Please look to my edit

Answer (score 0):

JSON.stringify turns a Javascript object into JSON text and stores that JSON text in a string.

Looks like the response is already coming in string type.Remove stringify from the code and try.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some css rules that hide the "li" elemets on your DOM or modifies the 'cars' class. Also be sure that the "cars" object is defined correctly and has a correct structure before stringifying it.

Comment: but on desktop works...only on mobile I have this problem.

Comment: Exactly, that's why I'm telling you to check if you dont have any media queries to modify the DOM and specifically the li.cars objects